# Blob a URL en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob

tengo una base de datos en la cual tengo el `blob` de una imagen, ahora deseo mostrarla en una interfaz creada con `rails_admin`, lo estoy haciendo según lo mencionan en https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields en la parte de output formatting, pero no se como pasar el `blob` a una URL valida para la etiqueta img, por ahora lo tengo así pero no funciona

```
    config.model Resource do
    list do
      field :Recurso do
        formatted_value do
          bindings[:view].tag(:img, { :src => Base64.urlsafe_decode64(bindings[:object].element) }) << URI.decode_www_form_component(bindings[:object].element, enc=Encoding::UTF_8)
        end
      end
      field :type_resource
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usar el método `import_pixels` de la gema `mini_magick`
Donde le mandas un blob y este te regresa una Image

Si quieres checa esta documentación [aqui](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mini_magick/MiniMagick/Image#import_pixels-class_method)